# What's the word for horse-headed human? (Opposite of a centaur)

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

**Centaur** - horse body, additional human torso, human head.

**Minotaur** - human body, bovine head.

I'm looking for a word for a creature with the head/neck of a horse and the body of a normal human. I keep thinking of constructions like "*equitaur*" or "*minoquus*", but nothing validating comes up when I search for them.

Any ideas? Something crafted anew would be fine, as long as it's sensible.

Comment: You can’t really use those two as a basis for a new word, because that’s not what they mean. _Centaur_ comes from old name the Greeks had for a [horse-riding tribe of people](https://www.etymonline.com/word/centaur) (only later did it become a mythical half-man/half-horse creature), while _Minotaur_ is made up of _Minos_, the king of Crete and the husband of Pasiphaë who gave birth to the Minotaur, and _tauros_ ‘bull’. Even though they look the same, the two words are probably quite unrelated, and no part of _centaur_ actually means ‘horse’.

Comment: An _equitaur_ (or _equotaur_, which would be more expected) would presumably be half-horse/half-bull, and a _minequus_ would be a horse related to King Minos.

Comment: They don't exist in folk tales, so there's no demand for a name for them. Make one up and force people to use it.

Comment: [*Hippocephalus?*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hippocephalic)

Comment: Ruatnec, obviously!

Comment: You must be thinking of [BoJack Horseman](https://www.mentalfloss.com/article/83277/10-animated-facts-about-bojack-horseman).

Comment: @JohnLawler is right. I recommend taking the hindu god Hayagreeva's name and using it to make a fantasy race. Just as minotaur was The Minotaur as in one beast that lived on the island of Crete but now the fantasty race of Minotaurs exist. Take the Hayagreeva and create the Hayagreevans, you could even make them descendants of a version of Hayagreeva and mortal women if you want.

Comment: I will say be careful and respectful if you are using real world religion in your fantasy setting

Answer (score 4):

That's called **Ipotane**.

[image: Ipotane]

[Ipotane — Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=ipotane&source=lmns&bih=635&biw=1360&hl=en&ved=2ahUKEwjl2fLYi5vpAhVK_4UKHUj4CMIQ_AUoAHoECAEQAA)

---

> ## Ipotane:
>
> In Greek mythology, an ipotane was a member of a race of half-horse, half-humans. The ipotanes are considered the original version of the centaur.

— [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ipotane)

---

Or **reverse-centaur** ([1](http://hillcantons.blogspot.com/2016/07/reverse-centaur-another-dumb-hill.html?m=1), [2](https://www.google.com/amp/s/tabletartpress.wordpress.com/2013/06/17/reverse-centaur/amp/)) as suggested by [Greybeard](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/330962/greybeard)

[image]

---

**Hayagriva:** Hayagriva, also spelt Hayagreeva (IAST: hayagrīva, literally 'Horse-neck'), is a horse-headed avatar of the Lord Vishnu in Hinduism.

[image]

[Hayagriva](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayagriva) — Wikipedia

Comment: The Wiki article seems to be describing a creature with the head (and torso) of a human. There is a picture of an ipotane in the article: there seems to be no "horse-headed creature". At https://dungeonmasterblock.freeforums.net/thread/1884/centaurs (and a few other sites) the term "reverse centaur" is used. Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satyr - Satyrs could be "horsey" around the face.

Answer (score 2):

According to Wiki, there are these specific named gods:

Indian: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayagriva

Chinese: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ox-Head_and_Horse-Face

The closest I saw was supposedly a half-horse/half-human 'kinnara' from Indian mythology, but it had no sources and none of the art in the main article depicts anything like this. I am disinclined to believe it to be factual.

I am not certain if a creature beyond a specific god was ever made in any mythology. As such, if you need the word in a creative project, having your created word following the etymology of any other mythical creatures that feature in the project could be one way to go about naming it.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, Tikbalang. In Filipino folklore. Western mythos doesn't seem to have one.... but the Philippines does.

Comment: Please add sources to support your answer.

Comment: Wikipedia has a lovely article on the [Tikbalang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tikbalang) - looks like a child/offshoot of Hayagriva.

Answer (score 0):

Tikbalang, a native folklore in our place here in Philippines which I always thought Minotaur. Apparently,  I figured these two were different.

Comment: Welcome Juan, to ELU stack exchange! It often helps in answers if you could provide a reference, e.g., to a web page where we could read more about this.

Answer (score -1):

How about horseman?  There's an animated series on Netflix called Bojack Horseman, and the main character is indeed a man with a horse's head. The word also has the benefit of being easy to understand without use of Classical Mythology, or classical languages.

Comment: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/horseman That is already a common word that means something different. "Three horsemen left the forest and crossed the turnip patch" would be ambiguous.